# ViewBinding dont work in android studio java

Tags: java, android

I have defined viewbinding in the build.gradle app section, but I am getting an error in the codes. my app is up to date.

```
 MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivityMainBinding
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(binding.root);
    }
}

build gradle:
    buildFeatures
            {
                viewBinding true;
            }
```

i tried uptaded and rebuild project but it doesnt work

Comment: Could you please share your error?

Comment: activitymainbinding's color red.so it doesn't see buildfeatures

Comment: Before `setContentView`, you need to initialise `binding` with `binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());`.

Comment: i do but it still doesnt work

Comment: Could you post your actual code?

Comment: package xxx;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    redline*ActivityMainBinding* binding;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(binding.*root*);
    }
}

Comment: You're still not initialising `binding`; you're not giving it a value. Insert the line I gave you before `setContentView(...)`.

Comment: setContentView(binding.getRoot()); like this?

Comment: Before that line, assign an object to your `binding` variable, with `binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());`.

Comment: its still not work gonna crazy

Comment: Compile see if it works, sometimes it randomly shows red but still works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.